# Username argument is invalid-CMOS

Tags: c#, credentials, progressive-web-apps, ms-project

As you can read in the title, i have a problem with the username argument.
I always get the error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The 'username' argument is invalid."

in line: `SharePointOnlineCredentials orgIDCredential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(netcred.UserName, netcred.SecurePassword);`

Any ideas how to fix it?

```
private static csom.ProjectContext GetContext(string url)
    {
        csom.ProjectContext context = new csom.ProjectContext(url);
        string userName,passWord;

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your username for PWA");
        userName = Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your password for PWA");
        passWord = Console.ReadLine();

        NetworkCredential netcred = new NetworkCredential(userName, passWord);
        SharePointOnlineCredentials orgIDCredential = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(netcred.UserName, netcred.SecurePassword);
        context.Credentials = orgIDCredential;

        return context;
    }
```

Comment: Related question, the answer might help: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/218956

Answer (score 0):

I got this error once too, the solution is simply to not include domain when using username:

```
NetworkCredential netcred = new NetworkCredential("userName", passWord);
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I get the same result. But maybe I dont unterstand your answer correct. Can you explain your answer in more detail?

Comment: @T.Steph Are you including a domain with the username? "@something"?

Comment: @T.Steph that is strange, when I use `username` without a domain, it works fine. Can you investigate further into if the username exists?

Comment: @T.Steph what happens when you append a domain name?

Comment: I can log in on the project sharepoint server with the same user/password

Comment: using the domain works. I get an error somerelse now but atleast the login seems to work now

Comment: @T.Steph Okay that is great.